# isearch/occur visible area in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm a little unsure about terminology here but is there some simple way to do an incremental search (or possibly an occur) limited to the visible area of the current buffer?

Ultimately I'd like to have something like an incremental [ace-jump-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use buffer narrowing to limit a normal incremental search to the visible area of the current buffer:

```
(defun window-search ()
  "Interactive search, limited to the visible portion of the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (window-start) (window-end))
    (isearch-forward)))
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after!

Answer (score -1):

Select the region of interest and do incremental search. Incremental search is restricted to selected region only.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Incremental search moves out of the selected region when it gets to the end, at least with Emacs 24.

Comment: As I understand it, the region is bounded by the point and the mark.  The point moves with isearch, and thus necessarily changes the region and also precludes isearch from being restricted to the region.  In fact, it is useful to use isearch to set the region in keyboard macros.